# Windows.Forms, showing a disabled form in non-modal state

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have some trouble showing a disabled Form in non-modal state. Here is the example code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // ....
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.Enabled = false;
            form.Show();    // works, but form has no owner
            // form.Show(this); // gives an System.InvalidOperationException
            // ...
            // ... my program here shows a message box, ask user for something
            // ... while 'form' is shown in the background 
            form.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Any idea why `Show()` (without parameter) works, but `Show(this)` gives an exception? In my scenario, `form` must know its owner to be shown correctly, so I can do the following:

```
            form.Enabled = false;
            form.Owner=this;
            form.Show();
```

but is this really a good solution?

EDIT: Thanks for the quick answers. Seems that we really found a bug in the framework here. In spite of your suggestions, I think I will keep with my solution, since disabling the form after the 'Show' gives an ugly visible effect to the user.

Comment: That or call Show(this) and then disable it are the only two ways that I can think of

Comment: My IDE says "Forms that are not enabled cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Set the form's enabled property to true before calling Show."

Comment: @Chris: I thought using 'Show' displays the Form in non-modal state, only ShowDialog does it in modal state, so where is the catch?

Comment: I wish I could tell you. The error message sounds like it should apply to ShowDialog like you said. Either this is a bug or there's a bug that your work-around is actually exploiting because as far as I can tell both Show() methods should do exactly the same thing and set the same properties.

Comment: @Chris: if you change your comment into an answer, I will accept it, as long as no one has a better idea.

Comment: Thanks @Doc Brown, comment turned into an answer

Comment: Microsoft will **not** fix this bug:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=525755

Comment: @serhio: +1 to you, as your comment is salient.  That doesn't mean we are happy about it, though!  I love how it's "Resolved" as "Won't fix".  How about "Won't ever resolve".  "Won't Fix".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That or call `Show(this)` and then disable it are the only two ways that I can think of.

Answer (score 4):

It's a classic cut-and-paste bug.  Looks like they copied the code from ShowDialog(), it is indeed invalid to show a disabled form as a dialog.  The user would be stuck and can't do anything anymore.  But they forgot to remove the test in the Show() method.  Just disable it after the Show() call.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. Since fixing this bug may change the behaviour of existing programs, I suspect MS will never fix this.

Comment: MS Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=525755

Comment: Don't bother, they don't fix these kind of bugz anymore.  Anyhoo, the workaround is simple.

Answer (score 3):

From Microsoft's reference source:

```
public void Show(IWin32Window owner)
{
    if (owner == this)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("OwnsSelfOrOwner", new object[] { "Show" }));
    }
    if (base.Visible)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("ShowDialogOnVisible", new object[] { "Show" }));
    }

    // Here!!!
    if (!base.Enabled)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("ShowDialogOnDisabled", new object[] { "Show" }));
    }

    if (!this.TopLevel)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("ShowDialogOnNonTopLevel", new object[] { "Show" }));
    }
    if (!SystemInformation.UserInteractive)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("CantShowModalOnNonInteractive"));
    }
    if (((owner != null) && ((((int) UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowLong(new HandleRef(owner, Control.GetSafeHandle(owner)), -20)) & 8) == 0)) && (owner is Control))
    {
        owner = ((Control) owner).TopLevelControlInternal;
    }
```

By the way, there is [a MS Connect bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=525755) declared.

Comment: Ok, but is this a bug in .NET framework? Looks like this exception was intended to be thrown in ShowDialog, not in Show.

Comment: yes, this can be interpreted as a bug. so you will need to disable the form AFTER  Show() ing it.

Comment: Thanks for supplying the bug report to MS!