# How to set Owner property of a Modal form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
class Form1: Form
{
    public void showNewDialog()
      {
         Form2 = new Form2();
         diagForm.showDialog(this);
         diagForm.Dispose();
      }
}
```

In the above code the Owner property of `diagForm` is set to `NULL`. How to set its Owner property to `Form1` instance ?

Comment: You're calling it diagForm and then using f.ShowDialog(this). You sure you don't just wanna replace 'f' with 'diagForm'?

Comment: I edited the code the way it was most probably meant to be. @user18246: are you sure that `Owner` is `null`? Normally, `ShowDialog(form)` sets the property automatically. `Show` has some problems with that, read my former post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094930/windows-forms-showing-a-disabled-form-in-non-modal-state

Comment: @DocBrown if he is checking for the owner in the constructor of diagForm it will be NULL

Comment: Original code made it clear why Owner is null.  Rolled back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the owner this way :

```
class Form1: Form
{
.
.
.
    public void showNewDialog()
    {
        Form2 diagForm = new Form2(){ Owner = this };
        diagForm .showDialog();
        diagForm .Dispose();
    }
}
```

If you check the Owner in the diagForm constructor it will be null, but if you check it in the onLoad event it will be form1

Comment: Thank you... In Form2 Iam using the following code in the load event handler,
this.Hide();
MessageBox.Show(this.Owner, msg, Owner.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK);

But the Message Box is bringing the other open windows of other applications behind it . How to overcome this ?

Comment: @user186246 I don't really understand what you want to achieve ? You want your diagForm to be on top of the messageBox ?

Answer (score 4):

```
f.Owner = this;
```

It's just a public property, so you can assign straight to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you check `Owner` property in `Shown` event in Form2, you'll find that it's set to Form1.